# Regex for password validation that have at least 3 of 4 different character groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to write a password validator that can contains at least 3 different character groups out of 4 character group.

**Condition:**

1. password has at least eight 8 characters.
2. password should have 3 different character group out of 4 following 
   chars groups and from each character group password shoud have minimum 2 character.

   uppercase letter

   lowercase letter

   numeric

   special characters (!@#$%&)

I have write regex in javascript:

```
((?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})|(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-]{2,})|(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-]{2,})|(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-]{2,})).{8,}
```

but this doesn't pass some of the condition.

Some of Valid Password:

a2w4hHH#

$#aaY5U5

YT7gh8q2

any Help will be appreciated
Thanks :)

Comment: Regex is not ideal for doing this all in one go. Why not just use separate regular expressions, one to check each requirement of the password? Will probably make your code easier to read too.

Comment: Using a regex here may seem to be an opportunity for some code cleverness, but it is absolutely the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to write a Javascript function for validating the password given your requirement of matching at least any three out of four character set requirements, rather than going for a pure regex solution. Pure regex solutions are easy when it would have been all four character set instead of three our of four.

Check this function which should work the way you need.

```js
function isPasswordValid(pass) {
  if (pass.length < 8) {
    return false;
  }
  var reg = [/[a-z]/,/[A-Z]/,/[0-9]/,/[(!@#$%&]/]
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < reg.length;i++) {
    if (reg[i].test(pass)) {
      count++;
    }
    if (count >=3) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var pwds = ['aB1@','aB1@aaaa','aaaaaaAA','$#aaY5U5','YT7gh8q2'];
for (s of pwds) {
  console.log(s + ' --> ' + isPasswordValid(s));
}
```